# Is $(0,1]$ closed in the lower limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

I hope that this is not a duplicate, I find many similar questions but none of them really ease my concerns.
**My Question:**

> Is $(0,1]$ closed in the lower limit topology?

It may be tempting to say that $(0,1]$ is closed because it seems not possible to express this as a union of open sets.
Note that $$\mathbb{R} \setminus(0,1]= (-\infty,0]\cup (1,\infty)$$
$(1,\infty)$ is open and $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-\infty,0]=(0,\infty)$ is open, so $(-\infty,0]$ is closed.
You may say $(-\infty,0]$ is both open and closed, but I really can't see that it can be expressed as a union of open sets.
Therefore, we cannot conclude anything from this. What I guess is that $(0,1]$ maybe neither open or closed, that's why we can't prove whether it is open or closed.

Comment: $(0,1[$ isn't an element of the LLT

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is a limit point of $(0,1]$ but not in the set itself. So $(0,1]$ is not closed. $[0,1)$ *is* closed (and open too).

Comment: Is (0,1] not open as well?

Comment: @Howardli621 Yes, as $1$ is not an interior point of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If it is closed then its complement is open. Since $0$ is in the complement there must be a basic  open set containing $0$ and contained in the complement of $(0,1]$. Do you see a contradiction?